# watching output of "ps aux | grep blah" in tmux will not work?

Tags: linux, grep, tmux, ps

I am trying to run this - 
    `watch "ps aux | grep myShittyProcess"` in a tmux session. This process `myShittyProcess` was also started in a tmux session. The `ps aux` works without watch command. But as soon as I put it into watch, it fails to execute. 
How to get this to work?

-- edit -

Found that resizing tmux into full screen makes it work. Something to do with `ps` output wrapping and `grep` not able to find within wrapped context.

Comment: This seems unrelated to `tmux`. I experienced this problem with and without it (without = `gnome-terminal` in my case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the question edit and [xzfc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/788026/180136), the issue seems to be related to tmux's line wrapping.  For something closer to a drop-in replacement of `ps aux | grep [q]uote`, if you don't need user information, try:

```
$ pgrep -af [q]uote
392 bash -c sleep 5 && echo quote
399 bash -c sleep 5 && echo second quote

$ watch pgrep -af [q]uote
```

The `-a` flag makes the output include the command line arguments, while `-f` lets you search the command line arguments as well as just the process name.

Answer (score 9):

Run

```
watch "COLUMNS= ps aux | grep TheProcessYouWatch"
```

Explanation: `watch` sets certain additional env variables, namely `COLUMNS` and `LINES`. This can be easily verified by comparing `env | grep COLUMNS` and `watch 'env | grep COLUMNS'`.

When `COLUMNS` is set, `ps` truncates its output to that many characters in a line, even if the output is piped to `grep` (or anything else). (`ps`, why do you do this to me?). Forcing `COLUMNS` to be empty within `watch`'s command is sufficient to make `ps` work as OP (and I) expected.

Btw, to avoid `watch` and `grep` processes being part of your watched output, consider adding `[]` like this:

```
watch "COLUMNS= ps aux | grep [T]heProcessYouWatch"
```

(Of course, I'd recommend to get familiar with `pgrep` too. Other answers will be helpful with this.)

Answer (score 2):

`ps` is utility that produces human-readable output, and rely on grepping human-readable text is bad idea. You should use `pgrep myShittyProcess` instead of `ps aux | grep myShittyProcess`. `pgrep` produces bare list of pids, and if you want less boring output, you can pass `pgrep`'s output to `ps`:

```
ps -opid,user,args -p `pgrep myShittyProcess`
```

To use that one-liner with `watch` you should enclose it in `' '` (not `" "`) to prevent early shell command substitution:

```
watch 'ps -opid,user,args -p `pgrep myShittyProcess`'
```

Comment: How would you deal with a situation where your base process is same, but you want only those that are using a specific config? With ps it would show the command executed and thus we can grep it...